# Python: Summing Digits in a Long Number

Tags: python, digits

I have come up with the following method for summing the digits in  number. It seems to work for numbers below about 10^23, but doesn't work for higher numbers. Why does it not work for higher numbers?

```
x=0
for i in range(0, 5000):
      x+=((number/10**i)//1)%10
print(x)
```

Comment: What do you mean by : *doesn't work for higher numbers*? Are you getting any error or wrong ouput?

Comment: It gives the wrong answer - eg it gives 9 for 10^24

Comment: where is that number in question, please give us reproducible example, so what was your input and what did you expect, and what was the result?

Comment: I tried it and got the right answer for 10**24 + 123456789.  Could you give an example that doesn't work?

Comment: number=10^24                                                   
The output it gives is x=9

Comment: @GregWhittier That's strange as I just tried 10**24+123456789 and it gave 36, whereas it should be 46

Comment: try `format(number, scientific=FALSE)`, is that number representing correctly, if not, that means you need to understand how R handles big numbers

Comment: @GregWhittier I get 46 using code pasted below.

Comment: @Ananta R? Isn't this Python?

Comment: oops, sorry...i just thought it was R, how do I delete my comments...follow Tim's answer..and what I wanted to do was from `decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(1e24)
Decimal('999999999999999983222784')`

Comment: Why limit yourself to 5000 digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving aside that this is a very inefficient way to sum the digits, and assuming you're using Python 3, add a conditional `print` to the loop:

```
for i in range(0, 5000):
    piece = ((number/10**i)//1)%10
    if piece:
        print(i, piece)
    x+=((number/10**i)//1)%10
```

Then you'll be able to see where it's going wrong.  Starting with `number = 10**24`, I get output:

```
0 4.0
1 2.0
24 1.0
7.0
```

You're not expecting those intermediate results, right?  Now you only have to figure out **why** you're getting them ;-)

The short course is that you're doing floating-point computations when you should be doing integer computations.  You get off track immediately (when `i` is 0):

```
>>> 10**24/10**0
1e+24
>>> _ // 1
1e+24
>>> _ % 10
4.0
```

Why is that?  Because `10**24` isn't exactly representable as a binary floating-point number:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(1e24)
Decimal('999999999999999983222784')
```

So the exact value of the approximation stored for `1e24` is `999999999999999983222784`, and that indeed leaves a remainder of `4` when divided by `10`.

To fix this, just stick to integer operations:

```
number = 10**24
x=0
for i in range(0, 5000):
    x += number//10**i % 10
print(x)
```

That prints `1`.  Much more efficient is to do, e.g.,

```
print(sum(int(ch) for ch in str(number)))
```

Comment: `str(int(number)).rstrip("L")` will handle more nicely floats (by truncating) and longs (by stripping the "L" prefix).

Comment: He's using Python 3 - there's no `L` suffix in Python 3 - ints and longs are "the same thing" in Python 3.  But, ya, in Python 2 it may be needed.  And I definitely do **not** intend to handle floats here:  that's gratuitous generalization, more likely to hide errors than to be helpful ;-)

Comment: 10**24 is an exact integer in Python 3.  1e24 is a float and (if IEEE double is the underlying float format) missing a low bit or two.

Comment: @MikeHousky, yes - and my answer shows exactly what **is** stored for 1e24 (on my machine - but it will be the same on the OP's - IEEE double is ubiquitous now).

Comment: Nice, didn't realize that.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't particularly answer the question but whenever you're looking at the *decimal digits* in a number you should use *the **decimal** module*:

```
from decimal import Decimal
sum(Decimal(number).as_tuple().digits)
```

---

Some advantages over the naïve `sum(int(c) for c in str(int(abs(number))))`:

```
sum(int(c) for c in str(int(abs(1.32))))
#>>> 1

sum(Decimal(1.5).as_tuple().digits)
#>>> 6
```

Note that

```
Decimal(1.3)
#>>> Decimal('1.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125')
```

because `1.3` is a floating-point number. You'd want

```
Decimal('1.3')
#>>> Decimal('1.3')
```

for an exact decimal. This might confuse your results for floating points.

A way to avoid this is to use `Decimal(str(number))` instead of `Decimal(number)`, which will give you a more obvious but less technically correct answer.

---

Also:

```
%~> python -m timeit -s "from decimal import Decimal" -s "number = 123456789**10" "sum(int(c) for c in str(int(abs(number))))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 70.4 usec per loop
%~> python -m timeit -s "from decimal import Decimal" -s "number = 123456789**10" "sum(Decimal(number).as_tuple().digits)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.8 usec per loop
```

---

But the real reason is that it's a just conceptually simpler not to think about the string but about the decimal representation.

Comment: No need for an import.  sum(int(c) for c in str(int(abs(number)))) does the same thing.

Comment: @MikeHousky; I realise that you can do string operations but why would you? Also, although it's silly to do this on most `float`s, yours doesn't even try. Try `number = 1.5`, for example. Mine correctly does it for all values, even if the correct value isn't what you expect for floats. I bet mine is faster, too.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Python 3.  The "//1" is simply truncation to an integer value, and you don't need that at all if you use // for the first division:

```
x=0
for i in range(0, 5000):
    x += (number // 10**i)%10
print(x)
```

As for 10^24, that is equal to 18, so the sum is 1+8=9. (^ is C-style bitwise exclusive or for integer arguments.)

Try 10**24 if you wanted 1 with 24 zeroes following it.

About your loop boundary.  To get the number of digits in the integer part of a number, add "math" to your imports and:

```
ndigits = 1 + int(math.log10(max(1, abs(n))))
```

If you know you don't have negative numbers, you can leave out the abs().
If you know you don't have numbers less than 1, you can leave out the max() and the abs().

Comment: Nope, `//1` is not an integer conversion:  it's floor division applied to a floating-point numerator in this context.  Example:  `5.0 // 2 == 2.0`.

Comment: @TimPeters 5.3 // 1 == 5.0 is what I meant by "integer conversion".  I should have said "number//1" is numerically equal to math.floor(number), maybe, but is that better?  You get an integer value from number//1 with just as many bits of precision as number had, no matter what.  And, number//10**i works too, as posted.

Comment: LOL - I didn't mean to nitpick ;-)  In context, the OP was apparently confused by the distinction between ints and floats, so while "integer conversion" would usually be "good enough", ya - in this specific case I think the OP needed more words.  Whatever, thanks for answering!